# Find Element with a certain css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Greetings

I have this structure:

```
<ul id="list" class="tabs">
<li class="list"><a href="#tab1">Dados do Responsável</font></a></li>
<li class="list"><a href="#tab2">Morada e Contactos</a></li>
<li class="list"><a href="#tab3">Opções de Adesão</a></li>
</ul>
```

and I am using jquery and css to make it look like a tab menu.

the css and I can define the currently selected menu by setting the class "active" in the li I clicked.

the question is I am trying to find the currently selected li without clicking on it...

I know it can be done using the $("#list").find(), but I don't know how! all I know is that the selected li contains the css class "active"

Can someone help me out with this one?

Comment: There are a lot of [jQuery tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials). I recommend to read the basic ones. The [API reference](http://api.jquery.com/) is also very good. Especially for this question, have a look at the [possible selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). Different topic: You should accept more answers to your questions. I don't think that 60% of your questions had no helpful answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/):

```
$('#list').find('.active');
```